# A non-Archimedean norm definition can be strengthened.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

See [Andrew Baker's p-adic notes](http://www.jon-arny.com/httpdocs/Elliptic/Baker%20padicnotes.pdf#page=19&zoom=150,0,588):

> For a non-Archimedean norm $N$ it is true that "$N(x + y) \leq \max\{N(x), N(y)\}$, with equality if $N(x) \neq N(y)$."

Having trouble proving this.  Please give a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not, suppose without loss of generality that $N(x)<N(y)$ and that $N(x+y)<N(y)$, and try to derive a contradiction. HINT: $y=(x+y)+(-x)$

Note that you quoted the notes incorrectly: you had ‘$N(x+y)\le\max\{N(x),N(y)\}$, with equality if and only if $N(x)\ne N(y)$’ instead of the correct ‘$N(x+y)\le\max\{N(x),N(y)\}$, with equality if $N(x)\ne N(y)$’. I corrected the quoted part when I edited the question.

Comment: To prove the required statement following this hint, do we need to know that $N(-x)=N(x)$? How is that clear from the definitions given?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs No, only need to note that $N(-x)\geq 0$