# Why is $\|T\| > 1$ in Monsky's theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Having come across Monsky's theorem today (that a square cannot be cut into an odd number of triangles of equal area), I was reading [his proof](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Monsky70.pdf). He introduces an "ultranorm" (or non-Archimidean norm), which is a function with the properties

1. $\|xy\| = \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$
2. $\|x + y\| \le \max\{\|x\|, \|y\|\}$
3. $\|x\| = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$

He notes that the $2$-adic norm on the rationals can be extended to an ultranorm on the entire reals. Then he continues his proof with an arbitrary ultranorm having the property $\|2\| < 1$.

He then divides points $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$ into three sets:
$$\begin{align}\mathscr A &= \{(x,y)\mid \|x\| < 1 \text{ and } \|y\| < 1\}\\
\mathscr B &= \{(x,y)\mid \|x\| \ge 1 \text{ and } \|x\| \ge \|y\|\}\\
\mathscr C &= \{(x,y)\mid \|y\| \ge 1 \text{ and } \|x\| < \|y\|\}\end{align}$$

He then proves that translation by a point in $\mathscr A$ preserves all three sets.

The key element of the proof is that there has to be at least one triangle $T$ with vertices from all three sets. From this he deduces that $\|\operatorname{area}T\| > 1$:

> For we may assume that the vertex of $T$ of type $\mathscr A$ is $(0, 0)$. Let $(x, y)$ and $(x',y')$ be the vertices of type $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr C$. Then $\operatorname{area}T$, up to sign, is equal to $\frac12(xy'-x'y)$. But $\|xy'\| > \|x'y\|$. So $\|\operatorname{area}T\| = \left\|\frac12\right\|\cdot\|x\|\cdot\|y'\| > 1$.

Now by property 2 of the ultranorm, I see that $$\|\operatorname{area}T\| = \left\|\frac12\right\|\cdot\|xy' - x'y\| \le \left\|\frac12\right\|\max\{\|xy'\|, \|x'y\|\} = \left\|\frac12\right\|\cdot\|x\|\cdot\|y'\| > 1$$

but I don't see what justifies replacing the $\le$ with $=$.

What am I missing?

Comment: In fact $\|x+y\|=\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}$ whenever $x\ne y$; see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468496/a-non-archimedean-norm-definition-can-be-strengthened) and answer.

Comment: That's it. I had forgotten that. Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: And now that you point it out to me, I notice that Monsky mentions that after giving the properties as well. I apparently had skipped that line.