# Totally bounded and closed implies compact??

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Is there a fault in exercice 9.3.1 b) from Analysis by Zorich? The exercice asks to prove that a subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is totally bounded and closed. But I have a counterexample for it: Consider the open unit ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a metric space itself. Then it is closed in itself and totally bounded, but not compact.

Am I right?

Comment: " closed in itself " ?

Comment: Are you suggesting $B(0,1)$ endowed with subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @YadatiKiran yes

Comment: it is not closed in $\mathbb R^n$ which is presumably what is implied...

Comment: @Carmeister but one does not write simply “metric space” and imply that it is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right.

For a subset $A$ of metric space $(X,d)$ to be compact, it is not enough that $A$ is totally bounded and closed (since $X$ is always closed). However, the correct assumptions to conclude that $A$ is compact are that it is totally bounded and **complete**. You can follow the link I included in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031114/is-it-true-that-every-totally-bounded-set-in-a-metric-space-is-compact/3031120#3031120) to a similar question to see that proof of this fact.

Comment: Almost certainly, the problem should have been to prove that a subset of a *complete* metric space is compact iff it is closed and totally bounded. This is true because the subset will then be complete itself if and only if it is closed in $X$. I do not know if Zorich accidently left off the word "complete" in the exercise, or if Jiu just missed it in the context.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's also my understanding as well. Regardless, I decided to answer the question as is presented here since I don't have access to the book soI couldn't check.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I don’t know how to upload a picture but there was no “complete” in the exercise. I typed the exercise word for word apart from “Show that”.

Comment: @Jiu - I'll take your word for it. You have to understand that people missing important words in their exercises is a fairly common occurrence here. Sometimes they fail to recognize that the word is important, and sometimes they just read past it. [It happens to me, too.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712278/why-is-t-1-in-monskys-theorem). So without access to the book, I did not have a way to verify that the exercise was indeed in error. But if you've double-checked, then I am sure that it is.

Answer (score 6):

$B(0,1)$ is closed in the space $B(0,1)$ endowed with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But this is true for every $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ if we endow $S$ with the subspace topology.

The requirement is that the set is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not in itself.

Moreover, in a generic tolopogical space X, given $A \subset X$, the equivalence " $A$ is compact if and only if closed and totally bounded" is correct in the case the ambient space $X$ is complete. In this case every closed subspace of $X$ is also complete.

Comment: The requirement in the exercise is that the set is closed in a metric space. Since every subspace of a metric space is a metric space itself, this is an empty requirement.